# What is the apparatus used in the 1998 Weizmann experiment ..?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality, experimental-technique

Basically what the title says...
For mode context, refer article in the link...
https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1998/02/980227055013.htm

I understand that trying [trying: using variable current in the observing device] to observe the electron, tends to collapse its state into passing into one of the 2 slits...

My question.. what was the device...?

Comment: https://www.weizmann.ac.il/condmat/heiblum/papers/391871a0.pdf
This is the link for the paper. Maybe of help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read the [experiment here](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/condmat/heiblum/papers/391871a0.pdf)

A detailed description of the detecting apparatus  is given.

Comment: for history note that I posted this at jan 21 at 9;50 and a comment appeared at the question at 9:52. I posted this as an answer because the policy of the site is not to give answers in the comments.

Comment: While I find quite a few terms beyond my comprehension, since the article makes references to a lot of other articles/papers/ publications i find this a reasonable answer....

Not sure why it was down-voted...

Comment: @Rony either ibecause it was too short, or because it contained the comment to you  link two minutes before he/she commented. My answer is short because it is a complicated experiment.